# Carthage Build failing with Cuckoo library with Xcode 11.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, carthage, cuckoo

I am using Version 11.3 (11C29). I am facing this issue while running the carthage bootstrap command. Let me know if any one else facing same issue.

Cartfile:
github "SwiftKit/Cuckoo"

Cartfile.resolved 
github "SwiftKit/Cuckoo" "1.3.0"

> ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
>
> /usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -project
>   /Users/*****/Documents/Workspace/******/Carthage/Checkouts/Cuckoo/Cuckoo.xcodeproj
>   -scheme Cuckoo+OCMock-iOS -configuration Release -derivedDataPath /Users/*****/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/11.3_11C29/Cuckoo/1.3.0
>   -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES archive -archivePath
>   /var/folders/82/_m5xwhxx4795wyxlhtw40ch509_hqq/T/Cuckoo
>   SKIP_INSTALL=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO
>   CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=NO (launched in
>   /Users/*****/Documents/Workspace/******/Carthage/Checkouts/Cuckoo)User
>   defaults from command line:
>       IDEArchivePathOverride = /var/folders/82/_m5xwhxx4795wyxlhtw40ch509_hqq/T/Cuckoo
>       IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/*****/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/11.3_11C29/Cuckoo/1.3.0
>
> Build settings from command line:
>       CARTHAGE = YES
>       CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE = NO
>       CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = 
>       CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED = NO
>       GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS = NO
>       ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO
>       SDKROOT = iphoneos13.2
>       SKIP_INSTALL = YES
>       STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT = NO
>
> note: Using new build system note: Planning build note: Constructing
>   build description error:
>   /Users/*****/Documents/Workspace/******/Carthage/Checkouts/Cuckoo/Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-Cuckoo+OCMock-iOS/Pods-Cuckoo+OCMock-iOS.release.xcconfig:
>   unable to open file (in target "Cuckoo+OCMock-iOS" in project
>   "Cuckoo") (in target 'Cuckoo+OCMock-iOS' from project 'Cuckoo') error:
>   /Users/*****/Documents/Workspace/******/Carthage/Checkouts/Cuckoo/Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-Cuckoo+OCMock-iOS/Pods-Cuckoo+OCMock-iOS.release.xcconfig:
>   unable to open file (in target "Cuckoo+OCMock-iOS" in project
>   "Cuckoo") (in target 'Cuckoo+OCMock-iOS' from project 'Cuckoo') error:
>   /Users/*****/Documents/Workspace/******/Carthage/Checkouts/Cuckoo/Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-Cuckoo+OCMock-iOS/Pods-Cuckoo+OCMock-iOS.release.xcconfig:
>   unable to open file (in target "Cuckoo+OCMock-iOS" in project
>   "Cuckoo") (in target 'Cuckoo+OCMock-iOS' from project 'Cuckoo')
>
> ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

Comment: Add the content of your Cartfile and the command that you are running.

Comment: whoever is downvoted this, please do comment the reason as well. to know more about it. So we can learn something.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue:

```
carthage update --no-build && pushd Carthage/Checkouts/Cuckoo/Cuckoo.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes && find . ! -name "Cuckoo-iOS.xcscheme" ! -name "Cuckoo-macOS.xcscheme" -delete && popd && carthage build
```

We need to run the above command.